# Infinitely stacked set

Tags: set-theory

suppose we have following sequence:

Let $s_0$ be a set. Then let be $s_1 \in s_0$ our next set. In general $s_{n+1} \in s_n$.

Assuming ZFC, I was curious about this:

> Can one prove, that such sequence always ends, i.e. there will always be some $k \in \mathbb N ,$ s.t. $s_k = \emptyset$.

I assume this to be false but I have been unsuccessful in constructing a sequence of sets that will go on infinetely. That also made me wondering, whether one can prove the opposite or not.

For example, I think that for $s_o \in Ord$ such sequence will come to an end since all $s_i \in s_0$ and $(s_0,\in) $ is wellorded. Is this true?

Thank you very much in advance. References are highly appreciated as
well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the set
$$
A=\{s_0,s_1,s_2,\ldots\}
$$
which exists by the axiom schema of specification (and possibly the axiom of dependent choice, depending on how the $s_i$ are established).

We have, for any $s_n\in A$,  that $s_{n+1}\in s_n\land s_{n+1}\in A$, contradicting the axiom of regularity.

**Edit:** As pointed out by Asaf Karagila in the comments, there is a well-defined rank "function" that prescribes to any set $X$ in ZF an ordinal called it's *rank*. This rank describes how "deep" it is in exactly the sense of what chains $X=s_0\ni s_1\ni\cdots$ exist (that's not the definition, but it's how I think of it). This rank is strictly decreasing on such a chain, and thus any chain gives rise to a strictly decreasing sequence of ordinals. Such a sequence can only be finitely long, so any chain is finitely long (although any set of rank at least $\omega_0$ will have arbitrarily chains of any finite length).

This way we avoid any form of choice.

Comment: Ah thank you very much, I thought there had to be some contradiction to the axiom of regularity. This is a neat proof, thanks a lot.

Comment: +1, but it might be worth pointing out why $A$ actually exists as a set

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom This follows from replacement scheme, doesn't it?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom The need for choice depends on when and how all the $s_i$ are established to exist.

Comment: No need for DC, though. Just use the fact we have a rank function.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's a much better idea. It's been too many years since I worked with set theory.